# OpenMP fibonacci function and use of firstprivate

Tags: c, multithreading, task, openmp

Why is `firstprivate` used in the below code snippet from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7883/girtd/index.html)? Removing `firstprivate` does not seem to have any effect on the final result. My understanding of `firstprivate` is that the value of the variable `n` will be initialized by whichever thread touched the variable `n` first, and then `n` after initialization is private to the thread in the task (parallel??) region. By default, variables in a parallel region are shared, but since the value of `n` is never modified by any other threads, there doesn't seem to be any reason to make `n` private to a thread.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int fib(int n)
{
  int i, j;
  if (n<2)
    return n;
  else
    {
       // removing `firstprivate(n)` does not affect correctness
       #pragma omp task shared(i) firstprivate(n)
       i=fib(n-1);

       // removing `firstprivate(n)` does not affect correctness
       #pragma omp task shared(j) firstprivate(n)
       j=fib(n-2);

       #pragma omp taskwait
       return i+j;
    }
}

int main()
{
  int n = 10;

  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  omp_set_num_threads(4);

  #pragma omp parallel shared(n)
  {
    #pragma omp single
    printf ("fib(%d) = %d\n", n, fib(n));
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you do not need 2 task directives. In fact, this is not efficient. You can remove the second one. This avoid creating tasks doing nothing but creating/waiting other ones. Besides, creating tasks is very expensive compare do running fib(n) with a small n so not creating tasks for the last n is certainly a good idea. Also note that using `omp_set_num_threads` and `omp_set_dynamic` directly in a program are considered as a bad practice (except in some rare cases). Environment variables are made to configure that.

Comment: Why would removing the second task directive "avoid creating tasks doing nothing but creating/waiting other ones"? Would this also imply that the taskwait would not be needed?

Comment: Once the first task has been created, you do not need to create a new task : the current task can do the job. This remove the overhead of creating one task. Since the function is recursive, this should significantly reduce the number of task (certainly x2 less). The taskwait is still useful to wait for the first task in the function. Put it differently, creating a task and directly waiting for it is equivalent to executing it serially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in tasks is `firstprivate` by default. That's mostly because you don't know when a task will be executed, so having data be shared may give strange results in many cases. I guess that the committee wanted you to spell it out if you really wanted data to be shared.

Btw, the point of `firstprivate` is not so much that it's private, but that it is immediately copied when the task is created. Again: if it was shared the value may have been very different when the task is executed from when it was created.

Comment: I understand now; ~however, where in the documentation does it state that data in tasks are `firstprivate` by default? [OpenMP 5.0 API Spec for `#pragma omp task`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu46.html) doesn't seem to indicate this.~ Nevermind, [Oracle API User Guide Ch.5](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7883/6nj43o69j/index.html) specifies this.

Comment: But the documentation puts some caveats on this firstprivate data environment that I don't really understand. "If a task construct is lexically enclosed in a parallel construct, then variables that are shared in all scopes enclosing the task construct remain shared in the generated task. Otherwise, variables are implicitly determined firstprivate." The task construct is enclosed in a parallel construct that specifies a shared(n), so why is n firstprivate? Wouldn't it be shared?

Comment: See section 5.1.1 of the OpenMP 5.2 standard: https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf . "*In a task generating construct, if no default clause is present, a variable for which the data-sharing attribute is not determined by the rules above is firstprivate*"